# why atmoicinteger (incrementAndGet) returns new value in every new restful (stateless) service call

Tags: rest

Restful is stateless, so how does it maintain its previous value during subsequent new service calls. i think stateless means no state will be maintained by server 
Even though we have cache-control=nocache in header
(i implement this tutorial: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)

Answer (score 0):

> Restful is stateless, so how does it maintain its previous value during subsequent new service calls.

Stateless, in the context of REST, means something precise -- and not what you are thinking.

As with most questions about the REST architectural style, Roy Fielding's thesis is the place to look.  In [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_3), he writes

> each request from client to server must contain all of the information necessary to understand the request, and cannot take advantage of any stored context on the server. Session state is therefore kept entirely on the client.

I recommend comparing HTTP with FTP, to get a sense of the difference between stateless and stateful requests.

> i think stateless means no state will be maintained by server

"Resources" have state -- see Fielding on [Resource and Resource Identifiers](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_1) and [Representations](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_2_1_2).

A *different* idea is that the web server is segmented into two parts that can be scaled independently - stateless compute and a stable storage appliance (aka a database).  That kind of separation isn't mandated by REST -- part of the point of rest is that the implementation details of the server are not constrained beyond the requirement that they support the uniform interface.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: i modified my code as: @RequestMapping(value="/greeting", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
     long newVal = counter.incrementAndGet();
     long prevValue = counter.getAndSet(0);
     System.out.println(prevValue);
        return new Greeting(newVal,
                            String.format(template, name));
    } 
//included newVal, preval and sysout line
so everytime browser hits the service it get value from the state stored by server and code is overwriting that value (atmoiclong is volatile)